# PortAudio UI control thread vs. audio thread

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

I'm working on a personal command-line driven sound application https://github.com/aparks5/synthcastle and I've run into some trouble.

Question: How can I have a control thread communicate to an audio thread without interruption of the audio?

I want to be able to pass commands from the command line to the audio thread and return back to the command line for further sound manipulation.

The problem is, without multithreading, that if I invoke a command such as "loop 4" (to repeat a pattern 4 times), my "loop" command just waits until the loop finishes before returning execution to the user.

I tried another paradigm by creating a control thread and audio thread, where invoking "loop" immediately returns, caching the passed data along with enqueuing a command to lock-free queue.

In `main.cxx`:

```cpp
    userData.server = server;
    std::shared_ptr<MixerStream> stream = std::make_shared<MixerStream>(SAMPLE_RATE, &userData);
    std::thread control(controlThread, stream);
    // todo: move graphics thread out of audio thread
    std::thread audio(audioThread, stream);
    audio.detach();
    control.join();
```

However, when I poll the queue from the audio thread, the data is corrupted and doesn't play in its entirety, only the last bit is played.

```
int MixerStream::paCallbackMethod(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer,
...
    for (size_t sampIdx = 0; sampIdx < framesPerBuffer; sampIdx++)
    {
...
        output = m_mixer();
        output = clip(output);
        *out++ = output;
        *out++ = output;
        writeBuff[sampIdx] = output;
        g_buffer[sampIdx] = static_cast<float>(output*1.0);
    }

    g_ready = true;

    while (m_callbackData->commandsToAudioCallback->size_approx()) {
        Commands cmd = *(m_callbackData->commandsToAudioCallback->peek());
        m_callbackData->commandsToAudioCallback->pop();
        switch (cmd) {
        case Commands::START_LOOP:
            m_bLoop = true;
            while (m_loopTimes > 0) {
                playPattern(m_pattern, m_bpm);
                m_loopTimes--;
            }
            break;
        case Commands::START_RECORDING:
            m_callbackData->server->openWrite();
            break;
        case Commands::STOP_RECORDING:
            m_callbackData->server->closeWrite();
            break;
        }

        m_callbackData->commandsFromAudioCallback->enqueue(cmd); // return command to main thread for deletion
    }

    ...
}
```

It's clear that nothing should be invoked in `paCallbackMethod` except for the generation of audio.

It's almost as if I need a third thread in between the UI and the audio, but this doesn't make sense to me.

I'm totally new to multithreading so any pointers as to how I can make control appear seamless would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: It's not going to be a perfect solution but my conclusion at the end of my question, creating a third thread so UI -> Control -> Audio actually produced the desired result. I can make loops in the UI, the control thread will poll the stream continuously if it's ready to play, and will issue the commands while the UI is ready to accept new commands. I'm just waiting for it to produce glitches when I try continuous control.

Comment: I hear you, but I disagree. The issue of communication between threads is so incredibly common in any kind of interactive application, from video players, to games, to streaming audio applications, that I'm sure that I'm not the only one to have encountered this problem. Audio is so particularly sensitive to interruptions because we perceive it easily that I think this cannot be sufficiently made generic.

Comment: "Communicaton between threads": that would be mutexes and condition variables. Maybe atomics. The End. That's the answer to that, in general. Anything beyond that is application specific, by definition, and would not be useful in any kind of a general context.

Comment: It's not going to be a perfect solution but my conclusion at the end of my question, creating a third thread so UI -> Control -> Audio actually produced the desired result. I can make loops in the UI, the control thread will poll the stream continuously if it's ready to play, and will issue the commands while the UI is ready to accept new commands. I'm just waiting for it to produce glitches when I try continuous control.